# How to Retrieve Spotify Playlist Metadata on Website?

Tags: javascript, html, spotify

I'm trying to retrieve some metadata from a Spotify playlist on a website, not to be launched in the Spotify application.  One example I have seen out in the wild is a website called [ShareMyPlaylists](http://sharemyplaylists.com/).

It is able to retrieve the playlist name, number of tracks, duration, track lists, and more.  Does anyone know how a site like this is able to get this metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the spotify api from spotify.com.

It's not available for plain javascript, you need server side script as well.

Here you have links to all api's: http://www.spotify.com/se/about/spotify-on-the-web/developer-resources/

Answer (score 0):

You need this: https://github.com/liesen/spotify-api-server